# how to test space not availabe functionality

Tags: android, cordova

I have the following piece of code that checks whether there's available 8Mb before starting downloading a file:

```
var spaceRequired = 8 * 1024 * 1024;
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, spaceRequired, function (fs) {
    createDirs(fs).then(function () {
        def.resolve()
    });
}, function (error) {
    if (error.code === FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
```

This is javascript, but it uses Android's API through Cordova platform interface.

My question is what would be the easiest way to test that `FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR` exception is actually thrown if there is no available 8Mb of space? My idea was to use `adb shell` to put some big file into `/data/` folder to occupy all available space, but I can't access `/data` through ADB if it's not run as a root on the device.

Comment: that's hard to test, why don't you ask for a bit more than the available space? and then ask for a bit less than the available space, if both of them work, it should work for 8Mb

Comment: thanks, yeah, I tried to request like 1Tb, and it worked :). How do I know how much available space I have?

Comment: I think you have an storage option on the settings app where you can see the available storage, and maybe you can see it too connecting the phone to the pc with the usb cable

Comment: yeah, I can see it in the settings app, will try that, thanks. In order to see available space using USB cable I need to run ADB as a root on the device, otherwise I'm not allowed to browse `/data` folder (internal storage)

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing this is to use the instance method

```
File$getFreeSpace()
```

for the given directory that you want to save your files to.

Consider also consulting the [Android Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#GetFreeSpace) concerning this topic.
They recommend to allow to write to the disc if the

> "*file system is less than 90% full.*"

So you could query the space in the root folder with the instance method and compare to the hardware disc space.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I would do just that, but unfortunately Cordova doesn't expose API for that operation and I don't have time to write plugin myself.